# Angular lazy loading modules with feature flags

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular-router

Is it possible to dynamically change which module is lazy loaded based on a flag?  For example, I want to load module A if the flag is enabled, otherwise load module B.  The key requirement is that it should use the same `path`, regardless of which module is loaded.

**Attempt #1 - dynamic loadChildren()**

```
// Use a service to get the flag. This service would be injected somewhere?
let someFlag = this.someService.getFlagValue();

const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'routeA',
    loadChildren: () => {
      if (someFlag === true) {
        return import('./A.module').then(m => m.ModuleA);
      } else {
        return import('./B.module').then(m => m.ModuleB);
      }
    }
}
];
```

However, this just throws an error when loading the route:
`Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded`

**Attempt #2 - canActivate guard to replace loadChildren**

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'routeA',
    canActivate: [CanActivateFeatureFlagGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./A.module').then(m => m.ModuleA),
    data: {
      REPLACE_WITH: () => import('./B.module').then(m => m.ModuleB),
      preload: false
    }
}
]
```

This throws an compile error:

```
Function expressions are not supported in decorators in 'routes'
'routes' contains the error at routing.module.ts
```

referring to the line with REPLACE_WITH.

Is there any known way (perhaps with a CanActivate guard) to affect what module is loaded?

Update:  I found [this repo](https://github.com/gquinteros93/same-path-for-different-modules) that seemed promising, but when implementing it I get the error: `ERROR in Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loadChildren')`

Comment: what is the compile error and where did you get `someFlag`?

Comment: Hi, you need to include all information (error messages, full context) in order for people to be able to help. Moreover, please aim at asking questions when the answer could help other people as well: if it's too local to your code, there is less chance it is interesting for the community (StackOverflow is not a service to debug code, but to solve problems).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () =>
      someFlag === true
        ? import('./new.module').then(m => m.NewModule)
        : import('./legacy.module').then(m => m.LegacyModule)
  }
];
```

Comment: Unfortunately this throws an error when attempting to load the route:  `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded`